# C : Multithreading using ucontext / Floating point exception(core dumped)

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to experiment with the ucontext routines to implement multithreading library.
I am getting "Floating point exception (core dumped)" while running this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

typedef struct {
    ucontext_t context;
}MyThread;

#define MAX 10
MyThread queue[MAX];
int rear=0,front=0;

void addToQueue(MyThread t)
{
    if(rear==MAX)
    {
        printf("Queue is full!");
        return;
    }

    queue[front]=t;
    front+=1;
}

MyThread* removeFromQueue()
{

    if(front==rear)
    return NULL;

    rear=rear+1;
    return &(queue[rear-1]);

}

static void func12(void)
{
    printf("func12: started\n");
}

static MyThread umain;


MyThread MyThreadCreate (void(*start_funct)(void *), void *args)
{

    MyThread newthread;
    getcontext(&(newthread.context));
    char stck[30];
    newthread.context.uc_stack.ss_sp =stck;
    newthread.context.uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof(stck);
    newthread.context.uc_link =&(umain.context);
    printf("Inside the mythreadcreate before makecontext \n");
    makecontext(&newthread.context,**(void(*)(void))start_funct,1, args);**
    printf("Inside the mythreadcreate after  makecontext \n");
    addToQueue(newthread);

    return newthread;

}

void MyThreadYield(void)
{

    MyThread* a=removeFromQueue();
    printf("Before swapping the context \n");
    swapcontext(&umain.context,&(a->context));

    printf("After the swapping the context \n");
}


int main(void)
{

    int i=0;

    printf("Inside the main \n");

    MyThreadCreate(func12,&i);

    //getcontext(&(umain.context));

    MyThreadYield();



}
```

Output returned :

```
Inside the main  
Inside the mythreadcreate before makecontext  
Inside the mythreadcreate after  makecontext  
Before swapping the context  
func12: started  
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

Updated : added (void(*)(void))start_funct,1, args) in function calls.removed unnecessary function calls.

Comment: Ignore the call to MyThreadInit(func1,&i);

Comment: Have you tried running it within debugger?

Comment: Can you suggest any debugger for multithreading programs?

Comment: Gdb works. Just run the program and when it crashes do `thread apply all backtrace`.

Comment: I'm no multithreading expert... but any reason to not use pthreads? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getcontext#Specification

Comment: To understand basic level of multithreading. Final objective is to build multithreading library using ucontext functions.

Answer (score 2):

The stack allocated to newthread's context is a first problem:

```
char stck[30];
newthread.context.uc_stack.ss_sp =stck;
```

"stck" is allocated on the stack of the `MyThreadCreate` function. It goes out of scope once the function returns, so `newthread.context.uc_stack.ss_sp` points to some memory somewhere in the stack of the original thread.

Concretely, newthread and the new original thread "share" the same stack at that point, which leads to a core dump (they potentially overwrite themselves).
Allocate proper memory for `newthread.context.uc_stack.ss_sp`, for with `malloc`.

Now, [many platforms won't allow code to be contained in the heap](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/System-V-contexts.html). The stack is intrissically containing code instructions to be executed.
This will result in a program failure when the context gets executed.

The link above gives indications about how to allow a memory segment to contain code to be executed.
Alternatively a simple solution is to use some memory on the stack that won't be discarded until the context is not used anymore (e.g. an array declared in `main`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Can you suggest any good debugger to test multithreading programs?

Comment: I tried running the code with the suggestion mentioned above , now there is a segmentation fault(instead of floating point exception). I also tried defining the variable globally but it is still giving segmentation fault.

Comment: I edited my answer to add a second problem that I overlooked, more deeply related with the use of ucontext itself. Hope this will help.

Comment: For the second part, I am not using context from function I returned from.Hence the context I was expecting was not from the createcontext but from the yield() where context was swapped with the one in the quese. (swapcontext saves current context and then switch to another context).
For the first part, I tried declaring stack in the main and passing to function, problem persist. So i started declaring variables and functions as static.After doing permutations i found the main problem.
I just declared the 'newthread' in mythreadcreate as static and it is working now.

Comment: I am trying to think about it but still not sure why it would it be. may be static variables stored for entire program duration. But now another question is "what about the stack which is not declared static?". Is that stack really used? or it is somehow stored along main static variable sturcture!

Comment: Good test. Statics have indeed the same life span as the process. But globals too, and 'newthread' is eventually copied to a global array, so making 'newthread' static should not have an impact... unless the ucontext_t holds a pointer to itself. And looking at ucontext.h, there is indeed at least context.uc_mcontext.fpregs that points to  context.__fpregs_mem. If  the implementation of swapcontext uses fpregs to access the content of the __fpregs_mem structure, then the declaration of  'newthread' locally on the stack could be a reason of the segfault. Gdb could verifying this hypothesis.